# ng-model-options exec callback on model update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I need to exec a callback when the model is updated...

I have this case:

```
<input ng-model="field.foo" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" />
```

Is there any way to exec a callback only on the "update"?

Comment: did you tried `ng-change` over that input field?

Comment: You can also write a custom directive that requires ngModel, and then access the NgModelController in that directive's link function. http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/

Comment: You are both right, I prefer the `ng-change`solution, but, both work!